# Include django template file with Jquery html

Tags: jquery, django

I am trying to reload a DIV that has the following in it from before.

```
<div id="mydiv">{% include "comments/comments.html" %}</div>
```

What I want to do is this when I click a button;

```
$('#mydiv').html('{% include "comments/comments.html" %}</div>
```

But putting the django tag inside the jquery html function makes javascript very unhappy. I know that this can be solved with .load() but that would mean I would have to rewrite my entire logic which would break other stuff.

Comment: Any jQuery calls will happen after the DOM is loaded. While any `include` statements will happen before. So this approach will not work. If you don't want to use `$.load()` you could `include` into a hidden element, then use jQuery to `.show()`. I'd use `.load()`.

Comment: Thanks. Makes sense. I was hoping that it was possible to "re-include" it with jQuery. Guess I'll just have to rework my applogic.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Template Literals` and given your post date, they would have been called `Template Strings` in ES5.

> Template literals are string literals allowing embedded expressions. You can use multi-line strings and string interpolation features with them. They were called "template strings" in prior editions of the ES2015 specification.

[Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

JQuery keeps breaking when you paste the HTML code from the HTML file because it takes in a string, not HTML, and putting `"` or `'` around `{% include ... %}` will break from any of the same characters in your `comments.html`. Put backticks around your `comments.html` file then import it with Django in a JQuery method.

```
`<div id='mainpanel{{ i.id }}' class='panel panel-default'>
   <div class='panel-heading clearfix'>
      <b class='panel-title'>{{ i.itemfullname|escapejs }}</b>
      <a id='close{{i.id}}' class='btn btn-default btn-sm pull-right'>X</a>
   </div>
<div>`
```